# Detach validate['required'] from field in Jquery validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have been using jquery validation engine on my page. So here is my scenario:

I have a dropdownlist and couple of textboxes on my page.
I have to add required validation on one of the textboxes on selection of some of the values from dropdownlist not for all the selections.

So what i am doing here is this:

```
function EditDateField() {
        if ($('#ddlStatus :selected').text().toLowerCase() == 'xxx' || $('#ddlStatus :selected').text().toLowerCase() == 'yyy' || $('#ddlStatus :selected').text().toLowerCase() == 'zzz') {
            $("#DateField").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#DateField").removeClass("valid disabled");
            $("#DateField").attr("class", "validate[required]");
        }
        else {
            $("#DateField").removeClass("");
            $("#DateField").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#DateField").attr("class", "valid disabled");

        }
    }
```

But the error still exists when you hit the 'else' condition also.It suppose to remove the validation condition on the field.

Edit:

Adding disabled attribute causing it not to remove the error message on the field. How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you add 'disabled' attribute to a field, do hide the existing validation error message on that field like this -

```
$("#DateField").attr("disabled", "disabled").validationEngine('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

$("#Particular ID for remove validation engine on that").validationEngine('hide');

Answer (score 0):

Specify the class. You have to specified which has to be removed. Try this

```
 $("#DateField").removeClass("validate[required]");
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to remove all classes is

```
$("#DateField").removeClass(); // notice nothing in the ()
```

When you pass in the empty string, it tries to remove THAT class, which it obviously cannot.

This should have been clear from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).